# boto3 S3Transfer throws error AttributeError: 'ResourceMeta' object has no attribute 'events'

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, python-3.5

I am new to AWS and Boto3 and I am trying to upload my json file to s3. I have assigned the s3FullAccess IAM role to my ec2. I have python3.5 and boto3 installed. I am trying below code.

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
transfer = S3Transfer(s3_client)
bucket_name='test-bucket-oracle'
prefix='configurations'
transfer.upload_file('/home/ec2-user/temp/config.json', bucket_name, prefix+'configs3.json', ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption': "AES256"})
```

and getting below error. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfers3.py", line 4, in <module>
    transfer = S3Transfer(s3_client)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 259, in __init__
    self._manager = create_transfer_manager(client, config, osutil)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 160, in create_transfer_manager
    return TransferManager(client, config, osutil, executor_cls)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py", line 264, in __init__
    self._register_handlers()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/manager.py", line 514, in _register_handlers
    self._client.meta.events.register_first(
AttributeError: 'ResourceMeta' object has no attribute 'events'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `client` because it is what `S3Transfer` expects. You can check it here: [boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer)

If you check [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html), the `resource` (`ServiceResource`) is described as:

```
A resource representing Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)
```

And the `client` as:

```
A low-level client representing Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3):
```

And as you can see in docs, they are not the same thing, although you can accomplish similar tasks with both.

- [ServiceResource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource)
- [Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered yet. It turned out that I needed to uses

```
boto3.client('s3')
```

I tried `boto3.resource('s3')` since a [github post](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1235#issuecomment-323817506) was recommending that. Any expert who can explain the difference is welcome.